# Can not fire checkbox change event in Telerik MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, telerik

I am struggling with the checkbox change event.

Here is code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=Html.CheckBox( "cbDisappear")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js">
    $("#cbDisappear").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).attr("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
        alert(value);
    });
</script>
```

The above code does work in the simple html page and I suppose maybe the telerik.js has been conflited with Jquery.js.

Additionally, because it is MVC application I have tried the configure the HTML.Checkbox by putting:

```
<%=Html.CheckBox("cbDisappear", new { change="onchange" })%>
```

Unfortunately, still nothing happen.

BTW, Does anyone can tell me why one HTML.Checkbox will be displayed in firebug like this:

```
<td>
    <input id="cbDisappear" name="cbDisappear" type="checkbox" value="true"
    />
    <input name="cbDisappear" type="hidden" value="false" />
</td>
```

Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I give up HTML helpers, use HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this in jquery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change( function() {   
alert(1);
```

});

this should work for MVC also

Comment: Thanks for that.However, it is proved that doesn't work. It's really weird that the Jquery does work for normal page rather than MVC.